# Kivy returning error when I try to add a label

Tags: kivy, typeerror, python-3.7

I am working on a UI for an automated piano. For this I am using a dropdown menu from kivy linked to a directory where the files are stored. I would like to (for testing purposes) take what's stored in said files and display them to a Label, however I get the following error (c.f pastebin) whenever I execute the program. Without the label it works wonders and is able to return the filename. I've been trying to work this out for at least 5 hours and am honestly out of ideas, hopefully you can help.

Thanks in advance, pastebin link in the comments as I cannot seem to put it here.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pjB7kxHR

Comment: First off, just realized I initialized CustomDropDown() as d AND as dropdownn, so I fixed that already

Comment: I don't think `Label` has a `multiline` property. Try `fileText = Label(text=self.data, size_hint=(None,None),pos=
(250,545))`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson That seems to be the reason why it crashed, as it doesn't anymore so thanks for that!